# Add/ remove element based on presence/ absence of class

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm looking for the remove button to disappear but only if only there is no `.newCar` to be found on the page. The class `newCar` (and `newDate`) only appear after the Add More button has been added. (I've two different classes here because the field `.newDate` can't be cloned because I need a new calendar generated each time.)

In short, the Remove button should only appear if there is *more than one* car (i.e. the fields in the fieldset are cloned).

I've been trying various techniques and my current one is to use the .hasClass method but I'm unsure as to why it's not working.

```
if ($('.core:last').hasClass('newCar')){
  $(this).parents('#form').find($removeBtn).css('display', 'block');
}
else{
  $(this).parents('#form').find($removeBtn).css('display', 'none');
}
```

I've created a fiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/218csoy7/1/)

Comment: So you want the remove button to disappear when there is only one car?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I should have made that clearer.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your question to include the clarification. Also, you should look into [the `toggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first of all I updated your Fiddle, check the link at the bottom of the post. This is what I suggest.

1. You where only checking the 'newCar' when pressing the "Add more cars" button, you should also check it when you remove things. Because of that I made the check a function.
2. You wrote the check very complex. $('class').length is sufficient in this case (you can see it in the fiddle how I fixed it).
   You can check if an element exists by doing it this way:
3. You don't have to change the CSS for an element to hide it or show it, you can just use $('class').hide(); or $('class').show();. That does the same as setting the display to block or none.

Further I would suggest you check your code some more, there is a lot that can be shorter and better. But then again, we all start somewhere :)

https://jsfiddle.net/218csoy7/5/

```
if($('class').length) {
    //Do something because it exists
} else {
   //Ok, now it doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: I like this! Very concise. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I love helping when I can!

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is check when you click the remove button to hide the button or not. In the `$removeButton` on click function, do the following:

```
$removeBtn.on('click', function(){
    $(this).parents($form).children($fieldsetWrap).find('.newCar:last, .newDate:last').remove();

    if ($('.core:last').hasClass('newCar')){
        $(this).parents('#form').find($removeBtn).css('display', 'block');
    }
    else{
        $(this).parents('#form').find($removeBtn).css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

This checks if it should hide the remove button when you remove. It's just your code in the `$addMoreBtn` on click function put inside your `$removeBtn`. You also change the condition in your `$addMoreBtn` to just have the first statement. This sets the remove button to `display: block` when clicking Add More Cars to have it show up.

**Update code in a nutshell**: I set the code in `$addMoreBtn` on click function to show the remove button when clicked, and added the original condition check code in your `$addMoreBtn` function into the `$removeBtn` function. This checks to see if it should show the remove button after the current remove button is clicked.

Here is an updated fiddle:

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6kxw1xwm/1/)

Here is also a snippet:

```js
var   $form = $('#form'),
      $fieldsetWrap = $('.fieldset-wrap'),
      //$newCar = $('.fieldset-wrap .newCar'),
      $addMoreBtn = $('.actions .addMoreBtn'),
      $removeBtn = $('.actions .removeBtn');

// Add stuff
$addMoreBtn.on('click', function() {
  // Clone the first instance of .core 
   $('.core:first').clone().appendTo($fieldsetWrap).addClass('newCar');
   // Append the following html so new calendar is create each time
   $fieldsetWrap.append('<div class="date newDate"><label for="">Date<input class="datepicker_multi" name="datepicker[]"/></label><div>');
   
   $(this).parents('#form').find($removeBtn).css('display', 'block');
});
// Remove stuff
$removeBtn.on('click', function(){
   $(this).parents($form).children($fieldsetWrap).find('.newCar:last, .newDate:last').remove();
   
   if ($('.core:last').hasClass('newCar')){
        $(this).parents('#form').find($removeBtn).css('display', 'block');
   }
   else{
        $(this).parents('#form').find($removeBtn).css('display', 'none');
   }
});

// Enable jQuery UI date picker on focus
$($fieldsetWrap).on('focus','.datepicker_multi', function(){
   $(this).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
   });
});
```

```css
form{
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   padding-bottom: 80px;
}
label{
   float: left;
   clear: both;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
}
.fieldset-wrap{
   overflow: hidden;
   float: left;
   clear: both;
}
.core{
   float: left;
   clear: both;
}
.date{
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid red;
   overflow: hidden;
   float: left;
   clear: both;
}
fieldset, button{
   float: left;
   clear: both;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.actions{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   .button{
      float: left;
      clear: both;
   }
}
.removeBtn{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="">
   <label for="">Name<input type="text" /></label>
   <label for="">Age<input type="text" /></label>
   <div class="fieldset-wrap">
      <div class="core">
         <label for="">Car&nbsp;<input type="text" /></label>
         <label for="">Model&nbsp;<input type="text" /></label>
      </div>
      <div class="date">
          <label for="">Date <input class="datepicker_multi" name="datepicker[]"/></label>
      </div>   
   </div> 
   <div class="actions">
      <button class="addMoreBtn" type="button">Add more cars</button>
      <button class="removeBtn" type="button">remove</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. I'd accept it as the answer but Barry's snippet is that bit shorter.

Comment: Very true! It is a great answer! I'm glad you made that decision @Luke

Comment: In fairness you were working off my crappy script ;)